# How To Make Files With No Extention Behave As PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At this moment I have the following files in my directory:

```
index.php
about.php
help.php
```

I'm using these lines in .htaccess to call the files using no extension.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

So **sitename.com/index** works as **sitename.com/index.php**

But I want to remove extensions completely. My directory would then look like this:

```
index
about
help
```

How to modify .htaccess to read **some of these** files as PHP and leave others untouched?

Comment: Why do you want your directory to look like this? Nobody except you (and other devs) sees it.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to catch 404 errors.

You need to configure your web server to trigger a specific PHP page on error. That PHP page would then read the requested URL and include a file with the same name.

Here is some help to get started: [onlamp.com](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/02/13/davidsklar.html)

Comment: It should be ovious that it is not a clever idea to send a 404 header on every request.

Comment: It doesn't have to send a 404. You can very well return a 200/OK in the catching PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it with htaccess alone. You'll need to set your webserver to treat no-extension files as php files, and i'm not sure it can be done at all.

Comment: I've found this <Files test>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

Comment: This forces a file to be threated as PHP.